# Deploying static Next.js app to Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting

I have deployed a Next.js app to Firebase Hosting by running `next build && next export` and then deploying what is inside the `out` folder... However, when I go to my web app it only loads the index page. Even if I go to a URL that does not exist, for example: `https://mywebsite.web.app/url-that-does-not-exist` it shows me the content of what I have inside `index.js`, instead of the 404 page. In my local machine, everything works as expected.

Is there anything else I need to do so that the 404 page appears?

EDIT: Also, when I serve the `out` folder with `firebase serve` it does not seem to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in the `firebase.json` file that gets generated after you `firebase init`, I was using the configuration of a SPA. This means that I was redirecting everything to `index.html`, so obviously every URL was mapped to this file.

Comment: Hey darmendarizp, can you share your configuration on the `firebase.json`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't set up the integration between [Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run). Without that, Firebase Hosting serves only static files - so your JavaScript is never interpreted on the server.

Comment: But what I understood is that if I serve the result of `next export` (which generates static files) then I do not need cloud functions... In fact, I am not trying to do any fancy stuff, just serving a static site.

Comment: A static site should indeed be servable by Firebase Hosting. So if that doesn't working, something's going wrong in either how you generate the site, or how you deploy it. But there's no way to say what that is based on the information you provided so far. Check the `out` folder, to ensure it has your static files check the `firebase.json` config that it really deploys and serves that file, and if none of that solves the problem: include exact steps how anyone can reproduce the problem in your question: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the mistake was that in the `firebase.json` file, I was using the configuration of a SPA, redirecting everything to some `index.html` file.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out! 